Same color for variable values ​but on 2 plots (same fig)
I am trying to have the same colors for the values ​​of the same variable which occurs on 2 plots (same figure), in order to be able to compare them at first glance via the colors. But I can not. An idea?
I already tried this code, but it didn't work. The colors are not respective of each value of the variable 'Libelle_nATC_2' of the df 'tt_group_2022'. :
couleur = sns.color_palette("Set2", len(tt_group_2022['Libelle_nATC_2'].unique()))


Thanks for your answers!

some tools allows to plot(x, y, color) where color is column from table [x, y, color]. And it needs to create new column with colors - and this way you may try to assign the same colors for both data before plotting.

It seems seaborn allows to assign colors to values using palette and hue - python - How can I set the colors per value when coloring plots by a DataFrame column? - Stack Overflow

Yes, I already Try to use hue='Libelle_nATC_2' on both plot, but it assigns differents colors for the same value.
I have also already tried using palette, but without success either.

probably you may need  both at  the same time hue  and palette={val1:color1, ...} to assign colors to values manually

it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code with some data directly in code - so we could simply copy and test it.

I finally figured out how to do it. I made the mistake of assigning colors after having only kept the 10 first values ​​classified in descending order of my 2 df. I therefore assigned them before, (so on an index of around 60), then I reduced my df which therefore included the same color codes.
The 'husl' and 'tab20' palettes give colors that are too close to each other, I was inspired by the answer found here: 1
and so I used 'colorcet'!
Thanks for your answers anyway and I hope mine helps others in the future!



put code as text, not image
